# D365 F&O Dual write filter not working properly for null values

Tags: filter, odata, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I am trying to exclude some records to sync from F&O to CE via dual write to achieve this I am using filter in DW entity mapping as:

```
((Reason != "A") && (Reason != "B"))
```

This works as expected when I am having some value in Reason field, however the data does not get synced when Reason field is blank/ null. Can anyone please provide any pointer to me help resolve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could the problem happen before, or in any of the code that we don't see?

Comment: Maybe add  `((Reason != "A") && (Reason != "B") || Reason == "" || Reason == null)`. I don't know the language, but it could be a bit "special".

Comment: hi, I have tried this seems not to be working